# How to pass PHP variable after a delay with POST method

Tags: php, html, post, get

Usually for passing PHP variables after a delay I use:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;URL=page.php?variable=$variable\" />";
```

But this way I send variables via a GET method.

Is there a way to send them via a POST method after a delay?

Comment: May we know what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data when the page loads you need to embed the following in the body of your HTML.

```
<form name="SOME_NAME" method="post" action="./page.php">
<input type="hidden" name="VARIABLE_NAME" value="VARIABLE_VALUE">
</form>

<script>
var timeout=5000; //replace this value it is in miliseconds.
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByName('SOME_NAME')[0].submit();
},timeout);
</script>
```

Just change the VARIABLE_NAME and VARIABLE_value with your values.

Comment: Ok, how do I "set" the form? like, where do I put the variables?

Comment: I edited my answer based on my new understanding of your question